# How to use htaccess to rewrite a URL to remove a directory?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following URL:

www.domain.com/test/blog/index.html

I'd like apache to always rewrite the url so that "test" will be removed, resulting in:

www.domain.com/blog/index.html

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it nicely

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)test
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/$1 [L]
```

This will remove the subdirectory from the url as you have specified; It would seem any other problems you are experiencing would be in respect to something else in the `.htaccess` file messing up the SymLinks.

I would suggest looking at the Apache error log to pin point exactly what the error is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed it works, but now I get a "forbidden" error on my root url. You don't have permission to access /test/ on this server.

Comment: Have you set `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` at the top of the htaccess file

Comment: Mm.. already have that. I'm using a the default .htaccess file that comes with Magento.